# `checked` attribute on radio button input does not exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, radio-button, checked

When trying to create an radio button input and setting the `checked` attribute, the `checked` attribute never appears. Interestingly, the CSS for `:checked` state elements works as does VoiceOver read out for the selected radio button at the time.

Here's an Ember twiddle that displays this issue:

https://ember-twiddle.com/1c3c6686c49a0c8338e24acc66b05a26

You'll see that the `checked` attribute never appears on the selected radio button, but both the DOM element and CSS display as checked or selected.

Does anyone know what might be causing this apparent conflict?

Comment: Have you tried changing $('input[checked]).val() to $('input:checked').val()?

Comment: besides comment above, any of your `radio` buttons have a value setted, so when getting the `val()` it will be null or undefined

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you didn't even set value attribute to the radio buttons and also didn't change the `current` property in the `controller/application.js`.

You should change three things in the `templates/application.hbs`.
First you should include value attribute to the radio buttons `value={{option}}` and an action on the onclick attribute `onclick={{action 'changeChecked'}}` to specify the change. Since the `{{eq}}` helper itself returns `true or false` you can also write the checked attribute without the `{{if}}` helper as `checked={{eq option current}}`
The final input tag should look like :

`<input type="radio" name="colors" checked={{eq option current}} value={{option}} onclick={{action 'changeChecked'}}>`

After that, in the `controllers/application.js` you have to add the action `changeChecked()`

```
actions:{
  changeChecked(){
    set(this,'current',$('input:checked').val())
  }
},
```

And also, the return statement in the `whichChecked` should be changed to :

```
return $('input:radio:checked').val();
```

Now you can dynamically get the selected radio button in the DOM.

Comment: Ah. I think I'm confused in that `checked` is a user applied attribute and/or CSS pseudo class. I assumed `checked` was an attribute that would update as your clicked on those DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```
$('input:radio:checked').val()
```

instead of:

```
$('input[checked]').val()
```